# Max Sum in array excluding adjacent numbers

Tags: arrays, sorting, hashmap, dynamic-programming, hashset

maximum sum of an integer array such that if we consider an element a[i] then we should not consider a[i]-1 and a[i]+1. for example if array a = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2] the o/p = 5 and if a = [3,3,3,4,4,8,1] then o/p =18. What is the approach should I use.

I have tried dp but not working

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, we are only looking at every OTHER number because we don't want adjacent items. We can do this by summing the odd indexes of the array and summing the even indexes of the array and then comparing which index sum is higher. See the following code snippet for an idea of how this is done in C#:

```
    int[] a = {1,1,1,1,1,2,2};

    int oddMax = 0;
    int evenMax = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0 || i == 0)
            evenMax += a[i];
        else
            oddMax += a[i];
    }

    Console.WriteLine(oddMax);
    Console.WriteLine(evenMax);
```

This will tell you the highest sum of non adjacent numbers in an array.